# Reading, processing and writing a large number of records (30 million) from a table by splitting the job by days using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, large-data

I have a requirement to read data from table A, process them with some custom business logic and them write the processed data into another table B using Spring Batch.

The number of rows that are required to read are around 30 million in table A. So, in order to break this down to manageable parts (error handling, tracking etc), the plan is to read all the rows that belong to a day (Table A has a date column), process them and then batch insert into table B (I pass in start and end date for my job from which I calculate the number of days the table has to be read.). This way any exception occurs in any of the days, I can isolate the issue and restart my job from the non read rows only. Basically the goal is to break them into manageable pieces (split the job as per day), write them day by day and if any error occurs in between, I can restart my job from the day the error has occurred. Now for this reason I'd prefer if the batch writing is sequential.

So in Spring Batch, my plan is to implement a calculate the number of days (say x) I need to process, invoke the reader x many times (this can be parallel) (reader returns list of objects of varying size) , process x times (returns list of processed objects) and then hands over the list of processed objects to the writer. The writer is invoked x times and batch writes the processed objects into Table B (this needs to be sequential).

I've searched quite a bit about this but couldn't find anything that can be usable in my use case. One article suggested JDBPCPagingItemReader (an alternative approach), however my table doesn't have a numeric column to keep track of the row position.

I have also considered using a tasklet for this approach, however due to the large size of data, I found it inviable to store the data in stepExecutionContext (the combined size of all stepExecutionContext would be huge). I'd rather want spring batch to handle the data as it is designed to handle large amounts of data.

Despite my sequential requirement, I was able to get it somewhat working using a Partitioner. I have calculated the number of days between two dates and added them to the executionContext map. The reader is able read x many times, process it x many times but the writer is stuck in an infinite loop (still not viable from a debugging standpoint).

Here is the job config, partitioner and reader coder:

```
public class DataLoadJobConfig {
    public final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    public final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public Job CustomerJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("customerJob")
                .flow(partitioningStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step partitioningStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("partitioningStep")
                .partitioner("partitioningStep", partitioner())
                .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
                .build();
                
    }

    private Partitioner partitioner() {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();
        DatePartitioner datePartitioner = new DatePartitioner();
        datePartitioner.setStartDate(startDate);
        datePartitioner.setEndDate(endDate);
        return datePartitioner;
    }

    private PartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        partitionHandler.setStep(slaveStep());
        return partitionHandler;
    }

    private Step slaveStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("slaveStep")
                .<List<TableAEntity>, List<TableBEntity>>chunk(1) // not sure what the chunk size would be as for each day the result size would be different
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    private ItemWriter<? super List<TableBEntity>> writer() {
    }

    private ItemProcessor<? super List<TableAEntity>,? extends List<TableBEntity>> processor() {
    }

    private ItemReader<? extends List<TableAEntity>> reader() {
    }
}
```

Custom Partitioner

```
public class DatePartitioner implements Partitioner {
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> executionContextMap = new HashMap<>();
        LocalDate currentDate = startDate;
        int i = 0;
        while (!currentDate.equals(endDate)) {
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.put("day", currentDate);
            executionContextMap.put("partition_" + i, context);
            currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
            i++;
        }
        return executionContextMap;
    }
}
```

From an architectural point of view is dividing the dataset into day partitions, the correct approach? If it isn't is there any better way to approach this problem?
Or is this approach even possible in Spring Batch? Does Spring batch support designing your custom data pipeline? (where I can keep readers parallel but writers sequential?).
Or in the tasklet approach, how can I make spring handle the large amounts of data instead of me storing it manually in the stepExecutionContext?
Also in this case I'm thinking I don't need chunk size as its dynamic and depends on how many records I'm getting for a day. In this case how do I work around chunk size?

If I'm thinking about this from a wrong perspective please educate me. Don't hesitate to be critical. Thank you!

Comment: *however my table doesn't have a numeric column to keep track of the row position.* What makes you think you need a *numeric* column?

Comment: As per [this](https://keyholesoftware.com/2020/08/18/utilizing-spring-batch-for-large-dataset-summarization/) JdbcPagingItemReader uses SqlPagingQueryProviderFoctoryBean which needs a sortKey. The sortKey internally uses 'greater than' to start the next iteration of reads.

Comment: So why would it be unable to sort a date column?

Comment: Yes! You are right. This seems doable. Then what about from a error handling perspective? It will divide the rows as per the pageSize rather than day. And if an error occurs, I'll have to log the query of each read and then restart the job from that row, correct (Is this a correct approach?) ?

Comment: Oops - might have to rethink: [It is important to have a unique key constraint on the sort key to guarantee that no data is lost between executions.](https://medium.com/spring-boot-framework/spring-batch-pagination-with-jdbcpagingitemreader-8226855a53d)

Comment: Why not just regular chunk processing? Spring Batch will record the chunk it broke at and you can just continue processing. You could even write a chunk/item listener which writes the wrong/failed records to file or a different table so you can retry/fix those. Your attempt to add splitting by day seems to only complicate what Spring Batch already offers out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

A regular fault-tolerant chunk-oriented step should be enough, and restartability will be handled for you by Spring Batch.

If your issue is performance, then you can try a multi-threaded step (but you lose restartability). Otherwise, you can use partitioning (just fix your partitioning logic and make sure to have reasonably sized partitions). With partitioning, restarting a failed job will only reprocess failed partitions.